# How to show last added record in a table in landing page

Tags: database, yii, show, record

I have a table name `Business` having attributes `business_name,business_id,business_description,image`. Now i want to display the 4 recently added business in my landing page? How can i achieve this goal

this is my code in main.php, i want it dynamic.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="gap"></div>
            <h2 class="text-center">Recently Added</h2>
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="row row-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <header class="thumb-header">
                                <a class="hover-img curved" href="nandos.php">
                                    <img src="img/nandos.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Nando's" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div class="thumb-caption">
                                <h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/nandos.php">Nando's</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <header class="thumb-header">
                                <a class="hover-img curved" href="rendezvous.php">
                                    <img src="img/rendezvous.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Rendezvous" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div class="thumb-caption">
                                <h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/rendezvous.php">Rendezvous<a></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <header class="thumb-header">
                                <a class="hover-img curved" href="roasters.php">
                                    <img src="img/roasters.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Roasters" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div class="thumb-caption">
                                <h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/roasters.php">Roasters<a></h4>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <header class="thumb-header">
                                <a class="hover-img curved" href="themonal.php">
                                    <img src="img/themonal.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="The Monal Resataurant" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
                                </a>
                            </header>
                            <div class="thumb-caption">
                                <h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/themonal.php">The Monal Restaurant<a></h4>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

the recently added, section is where i want the recently added business.

Comment: take a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140064/sql-query-to-get-most-recent-row-for-each-instance-of-a-given-key

Comment: @Skullomania  thanks for your response, but i want this thing done in yii, not in mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'id DESC','limit'=>4));
$model = Business::model()->findAll($criteria);
$names=array();
$image=array();
foreach ($model as $list) {

//    echo ($list->business_name);
//                echo ($list->image);
          $names[] = $list->business_name;
          $image[] = $list->image;
                }  
                $a=0;
                $b=1;
                $v=2;
                $d=3;
for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
    $one=$names[$a];
     $two=$names[$b];
     $three=$names[$v];
     $four=$names[$d];
      $oneimage=$image[$a];
     $twoimage=$image[$b];
     $threeimage=$image[$v];
     $fourimage=$image[$d];

}
 echo $one;
    echo $two;
    echo $three;
   echo $four;
    echo $oneimage;
    echo $twoimage;
    echo $threeimage;
   echo $fourimage;
?>
```

This is my index.php getting data from business model, like an array and store each value in a variable then where ever i want to show the variable value i just echo it, here it is..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="gap"></div>
<h2 class="text-center">Recently Added</h2>
<div class="gap">
<div class="row row-wrap">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumb">
<header class="thumb-header">
<a class="hover-img curved" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $oneid=$id[$a]?>">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $oneimage;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="recently added" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
</a>
</header>
<div class="thumb-caption">
<h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $oneid=$id[$a]?>"><?php echo $one;?></h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumb">
<header class="thumb-header">
<a class="hover-img curved" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $twoid=$id[$b]?>">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $twoimage;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="recently added" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
</a>
</header>
<div class="thumb-caption">
<h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $twoid=$id[$b]?>"><?php echo $two;?><a></h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumb">
<header class="thumb-header">
<a class="hover-img curved" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $threeid=$id[$c]?>">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $threeimage;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Roasters" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
</a>
</header>
<div class="thumb-caption">
<h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $threeid=$id[$c]?>"><?php echo $three;?><a></h4>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumb">
<header class="thumb-header">
<a class="hover-img curved" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $fourid=$id[$d]?>">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $fourimage;?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="The Monal Resataurant" /><i class="fa fa-plus box-icon-white box-icon-border hover-icon-top-right round"></i>
</a>
</header>
<div class="thumb-caption">
<h4 class="thumb-title"><a class="text-darken" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/business/userbusiness/<?php echo $fourid=$id[$d]?>"><?php echo $four;?><a></h4>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if business_id is primary or autoincrement you can use this:

```
$bussiness = Bussiness::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'business_id ', 'limit'=>'1'));
```

for select 4 rows:

```
 $bussiness = Bussiness::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'business_id ', 'limit'=>'4'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, my main.php is static i am making it, dynamic, i just want to show recently added business(4). get this error  Non-static method CActiveRecord::find() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: yea sure i am gonna edit my question so that you can have clear explanation.

Comment: yeah i was wrong it just yii1 not yii2 and this way you change on your action when you render view you must send variables that

Comment: $sql='SELECT * FROM Business Order by business_id desc limit 4';

Comment: with help of this query u can get last 4 business rows from db

Comment: u can use CDbCriteria like this : $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
or your model  $last=Bussiness::model()->findAllBySql($sql);

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to generate model for your table using gii. [Read more here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)

Once you have model you are able to pull all records from DB by using

```
Business::model()->findAll()
```

Business being name of the model generated by gii.
Below code shows how you would display all business_names.

```
$businesses = Business::model()->findAll();
  foreach($businesses as $business)
   echo $business->business_name;
```

Hopefully you can figure out how your code should look like :)