# SQL find latest dates, why do we need the 'inner join'

Tags: sql, database

I have trying to get the latest results using SQL. I searched the website and found this old post from 'stackoverflow', link:

[SQL query to get most recent row for each instance of a given key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140064/sql-query-to-get-most-recent-row-for-each-instance-of-a-given-key)

I copied the most accepted answer here.

```
Select u.[username]
      ,u.[ip]
      ,q.[time_stamp]
From [users] As u
Inner Join (
    Select [username]
          ,max(time_stamp) as [time_stamp]
    From [users]
    Group By [username]) As [q]
On u.username = q.username
And u.time_stamp = q.time_stamp
```

The thing I do NOT understand is why can't we simply use below (ie: why do need the 'inner join' operation in this case)?

```
Select username, ip, max(time_stamp) as time_stamp
    From users
    Group By username
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) It doesn't work.  In almost all databases, it returns a syntax error because `ip` is not included in the `GROUP BY`, so the SQL engine doesn't know which value to choose (MySQL accepts the syntax but plugs in a value from an indeterminate row).

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most SQL variants (except for MySQL I believe) require that any non-aggregated columns in your `SELECT` list also be in your `GROUP BY`. Otherwise, for a single `username` with multiple `ip` values, which one should appear in the results? In this case you might know that the username/ip pairs are unique, but the SQL engine might not always know that, especially for more complex queries.

To clarify with an example:

Users:

```
username      ip              timestamp
--------      --------------  ---------
bob           167.49.122.122  2016-01-05
john          167.49.122.123  2016-02-02
bob           167.49.122.124  2016-04-01
```

What result would you expect to see? for "bob"

Should it be bob/167.49.122.122/2016-04-01? bob/167.49.122.124/2016-04-01? Both?

You might say, "Well, obviously I want the whole row that has the max date", but that's not obvious from your second `SELECT` even if it seems intuitive to a human.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that if you know for a fact that the username/ip pairs are unique, you could use your simple query with `GROUP BY username, ip`. Otherwise you have to use one of the more complex ways to get the right value for the ip.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax suggests SQL Server (or perhaps MS Access, but I'll be optimistic).  A typical approach in ANSI-standard SQL is to use `row_number()`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by time_stamp desc) as seqnum
      from users u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```

There are definitely other methods as well that do not require an explicit `join`.